# Django Session's Lifetime in Development Server

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I am messing around with Session in my webapp at the moment and I noticed that whenever I restart the development server (the built-in server that came with Django), the session does not reset itself. It carries over eventhough I have restarted the server over and over again.

Where can I set it so that whenever I reset/restart the development server, the sessions are flushed/cleaned out?

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be desired behaviour. Are you expecting the same in production? You certainly wouldn't want, say, all your customers' shopping carts to be emptied just because you bounced the server.

Comment: I was just trying to experiment with something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change run server file

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myproj.settings" \
  python -c 'from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session; \
    Session.objects.all().delete()' 
python manage.py runserver
```

see here Django snippets: clear session table -> http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/48/

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use a non-persistent session backend. For example,

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
```

assumes: Django 1.0-1.5, using the default cache backend (LocMem)

Using the signed_cookies backend and clearing your browser's cookies *could* work too, but I haven't tried it.

### Why?

Django uses the database as the session backend, by default

> [SESSION_ENGINE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#session-engine)
>
> Default: django.contrib.sessions.backends.db

As a result, old sessions are restored from the database when the development server is reloaded. This holds true for the file and cached_db backends too.